# Doctrine 2 Undefined Index in AbstractProxyFactory

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

We have a lot of doctrine models (~100), and we keep seeing this error I query certain tables:

Notice: Undefined index: id in vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 125

I added some echos to that file, and it seems to point to a model called Actor.php:

From AbstractProxyFactory:

```
        foreach ($definition->identifierFields as $idField) {
            echo $className . "\n";
            echo $fqcn . "\n";
            print_r($identifier);
            var_dump($definition);
            $definition->reflectionFields[$idField]->setValue($proxy, $identifier[$idField]);
        }
```

Logging output:

```
Model\Actor 
Proxy\..\Model\Actor
Array ( [actorId] => 204011809623315 )
...
object(Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyDefinition)[336]
  public 'proxyClassName' => string 'Proxy\..\Model\Actor' (length=58)
  public 'identifierFields' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'id' (length=2)
...
```

From what I can tell there is nothing wrong with this class. It contains an 'id' field, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it?

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @Column(type="integer", name="fda_id")
 * @var int
 */
protected $id = null;
```

To me it seems like 'id' is properly defined?

What's interesting is, if I change the field name to be 'fda_id', then the notice complains about undefined index for 'fda_id' instead. I thought it might be a missing primary key index, but I've verified that this is not the case.